# 'HelmCluster' object has no attribute 'status' when connecting to Dask release from GCE

Tags: python, kubernetes-helm, dask, dask-kubernetes

I've deployed dask helm chart on gke, can access to the cluster with distributed.Client.
Now I need to connect to dask cluster with dask_kubernetes.HelmCluster, but it raises this exception. Code works in my local environment, but raises exception in GCE. Cluster is already accessible with kubectl.

```
from dask_kubernetes import HelmCluster

cluster = HelmCluster(release_name='my-dask')
Environment:
```

reported exception:

```
RuntimeError: Missing dependency kubectl. Please install kubectl following the instructions for your OS. 
Exception ignored in: <function Cluster.__del__ at 0x7fa65a330b80>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/michelv_romei/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/distributed/deploy/cluster.py", line 196, in __del__
    if self.status != Status.closed:
AttributeError: 'HelmCluster' object has no attribute 'status'
```

kubectl is already installed and it works fine.

Dask version: 2021.11.0

Python version: 3.8.0

Dask-kubernetes version: 0.11.0 and 2022.1.0

Comment: Thanks for posting, and solving this! I think it may be useful to update the question title to be related to `RuntimeError: Missing dependency kubectl.` as well? So that it is easier for someone else facing the same error to find this in the future?

Answer (score 0):

Noting the [corresponding GitHub issue](https://github.com/dask/dask-kubernetes/issues/416#issuecomment-1063934471), where the question author, `@Vin B.`, was able to resolve this by:

> Anyway, previously I installed kubectl via gcloud components, maybe it made kubectl unreachable from HelmCluster object, re-installing it from default repo fixed the problem.